# How to set speed for scrollToEndOfDocument with objective c in mac os

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview, nstextview

How can I set speed for `scrollToEndOfDocument` of `NSTextView` or `WebView` in Mac os ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out: I took it from http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/57/topics/588

```
 [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping]; 
 [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:2.0f]; 
 // your code here 
 [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```